# python3 isin関数を使用するが順番通りデータを抽出できない

Tags: python3, pandas

以下のファイルがあります。
Df12元のファイル
url,url_category,todo  
A,app,0  
B,app,1
B,app,2
A,app,3
C,matome,4
.......
上記の形でtodoは1〜100くらいまで重複しないであり、他の項目は重複あります。

```
final_result = 
[[9, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [40, 41, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

以下isin関数を実行すると順番が変わってしまいます。
どうやったら変わらず、上の順番通りになるのでしょうか。例えば、9-0-1-2、40-41-0

実行すると

```
cnt = 0
for l in final_result:
    cnt += 1
    print(df12[df12['todo'].isin(l)])
```

結果が以下になりtodoの順番が変わってしまいます。
url_category,todo  
app,0  
app,0  
app,1  
app,2
matome,9

本来は上のリスト通り並べたい以下正解です。
url_category,todo  
matome,9    
app,0  
app,1  
app,2
app,0

Comment: df12のファイル情報追加しました。

Comment: `isin()`の使い方を誤解しているような？ 有無をチェックするだけで並び替えはしないでしょう。それから、`final_result`の2行分の結果は単にそれぞれが表示されるだけですか？

Comment: はい、そうです。

Answer (score 2):

条件に一致する `todo` カラムの index をリストにして `iloc()` で取得するという方法もあります。

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
  'url': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'C'],
  'url_category': ['app', 'app', 'app', 'app', 'matome'],
  'todo': [0, 1, 2, 3, 9],
})
print(df)

final_result = [
  [9, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
]

dfs = [[]]*len(final_result)
for nth, l in enumerate(final_result):
  dfs[nth] = df.iloc[[df[df['todo'] == i].index[0] for i in l]]\
               .reset_index(drop=True)

print(dfs[0])

## df
  url url_category  todo
0   A          app     0
1   B          app     1
2   B          app     2
3   A          app     3
4   C       matome     9

## Sort by final_results
   url url_category  todo
0    C       matome     9
1    A          app     0
2    B          app     1
3    B          app     2
4    A          app     0
5    A          app     0
6    A          app     0
7    A          app     0
8    A          app     0
9    A          app     0
10   A          app     0
11   A          app     0
12   A          app     0
13   A          app     0
```

**追記**

> 2行目もとる方法ってないですかね？

以下の様になるかと思います。ただし、データフレームの最終行の場合は2行目が無いので、そのままです。

```
for nth, l in enumerate(final_result):
  lst = sum([
    [j, j+1] if j < len(df)-1 else [j]
    for j in [df[df['todo'] == i].index[0] for i in l]], [])
  dfs[nth] = df.iloc[lst].reset_index(drop=True)

print(dfs[0])

   url url_category  todo
0    C       matome     9
1    A          app     0
2    B          app     1
3    B          app     1
4    B          app     2
5    B          app     2
6    A          app     3
7    A          app     0
8    B          app     1
9    A          app     0
10   B          app     1
           :
           :
```

Comment: 上記で正確に取得できるようになりました。有難うございます。

Comment: ちなみに、2行目もとる方法ってないですかね？

Comment: 追 記 し ま し た。

Comment: 有難うございます。大変助かりました。

Comment: こちらCSV出力をto_csvで行うとしているのですが、可能ですよね

Comment: はい、データフレームなので可能です。

Comment: 有難うございます。大変助かりました。

Answer (score 0):

こんな感じになるかと思います。

```
for l in final_result:
    wdf = pd.DataFrame()
    for x in l:
        wdf = wdf.append(df12[df12['todo'].isin([x])], ignore_index=True)

    print(wdf)
```

Comment: 本来listの中にある行数できるものが数百行になってしましました。

Comment: 何ででしょうね？ こちらでは元ファイルのデータを0～100まででやっても、`final_result`のリストの数にきちんと収まっているのですが。もしかして`isin()`のパラメータを`[x]`に書き換えていないとか。